# Angular initializing data with foreign keys

Tags: angular

here's the setup. Need to call api with foreign keys to initialize data objects.

**The API**

```
{
   a: [
      {
         id: "1",
         x_IDs: [1, 2]
      }
   ],

   b: [
      {
         id: "1",
         y: 3
      },
      {
         id: "2",
         y: 4
      }
   ]
}
```

**The client data models**

```
class A {
   id: string
   x: B[]
}

class B {
   id: string
   y: number
}

class A_DTO {
   id: string
   x_IDs: string[]

   toClient(): A {
      client = new A()
      client.id = this.id
      client.x = WHAT DO I DO HERE. I NEED TO CONVERT THE IDS TO ACTUAL 'B' OBJECTS
   }
}

class B_DTO {
   id: string
   y: number

   toClient(): B {
      client = new B()
      client.id = this.id
      client.y = this.y
   }
}
```

**Client API service**

```
getallA(): Observable<A[]> {
   this.http.get<A[]>("/A_endpoint".pipe(map(aDTO => aDTO.toClient()))
}

getoneB(id: string): Observable<B> {
   this.http.get<B>(`/B_endpoint/{id}`.pipe(map(bDTO => bDTO.toClient()))
}
```

I don't know how I can call the API from within the A_DTO model because if I inject the service then I have to provide the api in the constructor everytime I create a A_DTO object.
ie.

```
class A_DTO {
   constructor(private api: API_Service)

   id: string
   x_IDs: string[]

   toClient(): A {
      client = new A()
      client.id = this.id
      client.x = this.x_IDs.map(id => this.api.getoneB(id).toClient())
   }
}

// somewhere else
dto = new B_DTO(api???)
```

I could also just call the api endpoints from within the api service the get the nested objects using the ids. However I want to be able to just call toClient without having to do more work outside of that class(ie in the api)

```
getoneA(id): Observable<A> {
   // this probably isn't totally correct rxjs code but I think the point gets across

   return this.http.get<A>(`/a_endpoint/{id}`).pipe(map(a_DTO => {
      client = a_DTO.toClient()
      client.x = a_DTO.x_IDs.map(id => this.getoneB(id)) // I don't want to have to do this code

      return client
   ))
}
```

I could also just not use foreign keys (see below) but this duplicates data and I don't want to do that.

```
{
   a: [
      {
         id: "1",
         x_IDs: [
            {
               id: "1",
               y: 3
            },
            {
               id: "2",
               y: 4
            }
         ]
      }
   ],

   b: [
      {
         id: "1",
         y: 3
      },
      {
         id: "2",
         y: 4
      }
   ]
}
```

any known patterns or ideas for this. much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

### Higher Order Observable: MergeMap

You can use the higher order observable `mergeMap` for this:

```js
getallA(): Observable<A[]> {
   this.http.get<A[]>('/A_endpoint')
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(aDto => {
        return this.getOneB(aDto.x_IDs).pipe(
          map(bDto => ({...aDto, ...bDto}))
        )
      })
   )
}

getoneB(id: string): Observable<B> {
   this.http.get<B>('/B_endpoint/{id}')
}
```

Here's a dumbed down example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvsbxs?file=src/app/app.component.css) for you to play with.